# How to find proper parameter settings for a given optimization algorithm?

Tags: search, heuristics, hyperparameter-optimization, meta-heuristics

Is there any methodology to find proper parameter settings for a given meta-heuristic algorithm, e.g. the [firefly algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_algorithm) or the [cuckoo search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_search)? Is this an open issue in optimization? Is extensive experimentation, measurements and intuition the only way to figure out which are the best settings?

Answer (score 2):

How to find the best configuration for an algorithm is an open research question in AI. The topic in general is known as `hyper-parameter optimization' and there are a range of possible methods:

One of the most popular is [IRace](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/irace/), but other possibilities include:

- [Spearmint](https://github.com/JasperSnoek/spearmint): uses wrappers in Matlab or Python. It uses MongoDb,
  and Bayesian optimisation algorithms.
- [SMAC](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/beta/Projects/SMAC/) requires a python wrapper for the algorithm to be optimized
  and has a command line interface.
- [Hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt): a Python library which uses Random Search and Tree of
  Parzen Estimators.

[This paper](http://www.automl.org/papers/13-BayesOpt%5C_EmpiricalFoundation.pdf) argues that Spearmint performs the best, compared with SMAC and Hyperopt, but with significantly longer running times in some cases.